# use combinator with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I select a child of a sibling of `$(this)`. These sorts of complicated selectors aren't really my strongsuit. I've tred to get the sibling of this using the combinator `+`. but combining it with this confuses me. I don't understand when I see a `$(this` followed by a `, something)`

`$(this, '+ input.in')` is useless as it seems only to select the same thing as `$(this)`;

http://jsbin.com/oguhuv/2/

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've got a `this` to worry about, you're not really working with just selectors anymore. You have to use jQuery APIs to tell it where to look for more/different elements. Finding siblings can be done via `.next()`, `.previous()`, or `.parent().children(selector)`, depending on the situation.

The construction `$(this, selector)` is almost certainly a mistake, but `$(selector, this)` is the same as `$(this).find(selector)`.

*edit* note the comment below pointing out that `.siblings(selector)` is basically the same as `.parent().children(selector)`.

Comment: .parent().children() can more simply be written .siblings()

Comment: @IMSoP ah well I should have checked :-)  For whatever reason, it's extremely rare that I find myself wanting to go wandering around the DOM so that's not an API I'd be familiar with.

Comment: To be entirely precise, `.parent().children()` would include the current element, so would be equivalent to `.siblings().andSelf()` or `.siblings().addBack()`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply using something like:

```
$(this).next('input.in').children(selector)
```

Or

```
$(this).next('input.in').find(selector)
```

Use the latter if the target selector is not a direct child of `input.in`

Comment: `<input>`s don't have children, so I', quite sure the OP meant something different

Answer (score 1):

To use `this` as the [context for the selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1), you would need to swap the parameters: `$('+ input.in', this)`. Also, you forgot to use a `*` for the sibling of which you want to select the input children:

```
$('+ * input.in', this);
```

(Yes, this [really works](http://jsfiddle.net/JbaHu/)). However, using the jQuery methods to navigate the DOM would be more clear:

```
$(this).next().find("input.in")
```

Comment: In your example, `this` is the container (because that's whose click event is being handled), not a sibling of the target.

Comment: Wait, I may have misread that. I'll shut up and get some sleep ;)

Comment: What put me off was that your example was rather over-complicated (why use delegated events? why have multiple divs just to demonstrate one selector?). Here is a simpler example which shows you are indeed correct: http://jsfiddle.net/P5ePG/2/

Comment: @IMSoP: Yeah, I had used some code from OP's jsbin. Rather illegible, thanks for the better example!

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors in jQuery are used to either filter a set of elements (e.g. `.filter()`, `.not()`) or to find descendant elements (e.g. $('.foo') to search the whole document, $('foo', data) to search another object, like an AJAX response, or someElement.find('.foo') to search the contents of an element). In your case you have a single element, and it doesn't contain the target element, so no matter what selector you use, none of these will be able to see it.

However, your use of the word "sibling" hints at [the right function to use](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/). Once you find all the siblings, you can use a selector to filter that list; jQuery lets you do this all in one go, so your example would be `$(this).siblings('input.in')`